# Time complexity of code within nested loop

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Given

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
        Console.WriteLine(i, j);
```

I understand that the outer for loop runs 4n - 1 times and the inner runs 3n^2 - 3 times, however I don't understand why the print statement runs n(n - 1)/2 times. I am only getting n(n - 1) as my time complexity yet the slides say n(n - 1)/2. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- for i = 1, j varies from 2 to n => n-1 times
- for i = 2, j varies from    3 to n => n-2 times

...

...

- for i=n-1 j varies from n to n => 1 time

so number of operations => (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + .... +1
that solves to n(n-1)/2 (remember the formula for summation of n natural numbers - https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/groups/tatami/handdemos/sum/

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing much because the big O bound of both `n(n - 1)` and `n(n - 1)/2` is `O(n^2)`.  The double loop you showed will be upper bounded by `O(n^2)`, and this is the main point here, I think.